# Create Liferay public pages on server start

Tags: java, liferay

I would like to create a Liferay hook that creates public pages on server start.

I already have the hook bound to server start. But I have some problems with creating the page. **Maybe I am wrong about user, group, community**, etc. (remember that this hook doesn't have access to themeDisplay).

```
Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx(PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID));
long companyId = company.getCompanyId();
User defaultUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultUser(companyId);

long userId = defaultUser.getUserId();
long groupId = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyGroup(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId()).getGroupId();
boolean privateLayout = false;
long parentLayoutId = LayoutConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_LAYOUT_ID;
String name = page.getName();
String title = null;
String description = null;
String type = LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET;
boolean hidden = false;
String friendlyUrl = "/test";

ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId);


LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(userId, groupId, privateLayout, parentLayoutId, name, title, description, type, hidden, friendlyUrl, serviceContext);
LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();
layoutTypePortlet.setLayoutTemplateId(userId, page.getLayoutId());

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout.getGroupId(), layout.isPrivateLayout(), layout.getLayoutId(), layout.getTypeSettings());
```

The page is never listed...

Comment: So maybe the right question is: how should I get company, group, user, etc. for working with public pages?

Comment: I need a single button for this comment: If you're posting the same question in different locations, please link the two so that a) it becomes obvious if you already have an answer and b) anybody who has the same question can find the answer if it happens to be at that other location. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47932640

Comment: There is some example code for version 6.2, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37328258/1180235

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the leftovers of that old sevencogs hook demo code - [James Falkner has blogged about](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) it and resurrected some of the code. It might not be for the current version, but if there are any API changes, they're minor.

Pay special attention to the "Adding a Layout (Page) to a Site" paragraph in that article and compare it with your code.

Also note that "on server start" means that you'll have to pay attention to not create the same page twice. It'd happen on every single server start - or actually on every deployment of the hook that you write.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, the article doesn't reply where to get the correct group... (And yes, I check if the page hasn't been created before.)